# How to keep node mining automatically in qt wallet or console wallet

Tags: mining-pools, bitcoin-core-development, litecoin-qt

In the qt wallet, manually need to start the mining process in wallet console by giving generate nblock. so is there any other command or solution to automatically mine the block and how to confirm the transaction.

Comment: Are you talking about testnet?

Comment: Bitcoin Core does not contain a miner (except an inefficient one for regtest).

Comment: yes , in the testnet. Another thing the after the confirmation of block the balance is not showing in my qt wallet.